# I was working on solidity project and got the error that Identifier not found or not unique

Tags: solidity, javascript

```
/ SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// SPDX-Licence-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >= 0.7.0 < 0.9.0;
contract ChatApp {
  // USER STRUCT
  struct user {

    string name;
    friend[]friendlist;

  }

  struct friend {
    address pubkey;

    string name;
  }

  struct message {
    address sender;
    uint256 timestamp;
    string msg;
  }
  struct AllUserStruck {
    string name;
    address accountAddress;
  }
  AllUserStruck[]getAllUsers;
  mapping(address => user)userlist;
  mapping(bytes32 => message[])allMessages;
  function checkUserExists(address pubkey)public view returns(bool) {
    return bytes(userList[pubkey].name).length > 0;
  }
  //CREATE ACCOUNT
  function createAccount(string calldata name)external {
    require(theUserExists(msg.sender) == false, "User already exists");
    require(bytes(name).length > 0, "Username cannot be empty");
    userList[msg.sender].name = name;
    getAllUsers.push(AllUsersStruck(name, msg.sender));
  }
  //GET USERNAME
  function getUsername(address pubkey)external view returns(string memory) {}
  function addFriend(address friend_key, string calldata name)external {
    require(checkUserExists(msg.sender), "Create an account first");
    require(checkUserExists(friend_key), "User is not registered!");
    require(msg.sender |= friend_key, "Users cannot add themselves as friend");
    require(checkAlreadyFriend(msg.sender, friend_key) == false, "These users are already friends");

    _addFriend(msg.sender, friend_key, name);
    _addFriend(friend_key, msg.sender, userList[msg.sender].name);

    //checkAlreadyFriends
    function checkAlreadyFriend(address pubkey1, address pubkey2)internal view returns(bool) {
      if (userList[pubkey1].friendList.length > userList[pubkey2].friendList.length) {
        address tmp = pubkey1;
        pubkey1 = pubkey2;
        pubkey = tmp;
      }
      for (uint256 i = 0; i < userList[pubkey].friendList.length; i++) {
        if (userList[pubkey1].friendList[i].pubkey == pubkey2)
          return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
    function _addFriend(address me, address friend_key, string memory name)internal {
      friend memory newFriend = friend(friend_key, name);
      userList[me].friendList.push(newFriend);
    }
    //GET MY FRIEND
    function getMyFriendList()external view returns(friend[]memory) {
      return userList[msg.sender].friendList;
    }
    //get chat code
    function _getChatCode(address pubkey1, address pubkey2)internal pure returns(bytes32) {
      if (pubkey1 < pubkey2) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(pubkey1, pubkey2));
      } else
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(pubkey1, pubkey2));
    }
    //SEND MESSAGE
    function sendMessage(address friend_key, string calldata _msg)external {
      require(checkUserExists(msg.sender), "Create an account first");
      require(checkUserExists(friend_key), "User is not registered");
      require(checkAlreadyFriends(msg.sender, friend_key), "You are not friend with the given user");
      bytes32 chatCode = _getChatCode(msg.sender, friend_key);
      message memory newMsg = message(msg.sender, block.timestamp, _msg);
      allMessages[chatCode].push(newMsg);
    }
    //READ MESSAGE
    function readMessage(address friend_key)external view returns(message[]memory) {
      bytes32 chatCode = _getChatCode(msg.sender, friend_key);
      return allMessages[chatCode];
    }
    function getAllUsers()public view returns(AllUsersStruck[] - memory) {
      return getAllUsers
    }

  }
```

Comment: This usually means there is a function or a variable missing. For example if you are calling a function or a variable,  but you misspelled the name (so now you are calling a function that doesn't exist) you will get that kind of error.  Do you maybe have the rest of the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check my [Github](https://github.com/mehdiiwani/ChatDApp) to clone the code from there

```
  // Here is the complete working code for it
  // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    
    pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
    
    contract ChatApp {
        // USER STRUCT
        struct User {
            string name;
            Friend[] friendList;
        }
        struct Friend {
            address pubkey;
            string name;
        }
    
        struct Message {
            address sender;
            uint256 timestamp;
            string msg;
        }
    
        struct AllUserStruct {
            string name;
            address accountAddress;
        }
    
        AllUserStruct[] public allUsers;
        mapping(address => User) public userList;
        mapping(bytes32 => Message[]) public allMessages;
    
        function checkUserExists(address pubkey) public view returns (bool) {
            return bytes(userList[pubkey].name).length > 0;
        }
    
        //CREATE ACCOUNT
        function createAccount(string memory name) external {
            require(checkUserExists(msg.sender) == false, "User already exists");
            require(bytes(name).length > 0, "Username cannot be empty");
            userList[msg.sender].name = name;
            allUsers.push(AllUserStruct(name, msg.sender));
        }
    
        //GET USERNAME
        function getUsername(address pubkey) external view returns (string memory) {
            return userList[pubkey].name;
        }
    
        function addFriend(address friend_key, string memory name) external {
            require(checkUserExists(msg.sender), "Create an account first");
            require(checkUserExists(friend_key), "User is not registered!");
            require(
                msg.sender != friend_key,
                "Users cannot add themselves as friend"
            );
            require(
                checkAlreadyFriend(msg.sender, friend_key) == false,
                "These users are already friends"
            );
    
            _addFriend(msg.sender, friend_key, name);
            _addFriend(friend_key, msg.sender, userList[msg.sender].name);
        }
    
        //checkAlreadyFriends
        function checkAlreadyFriend(address pubkey1, address pubkey2)
            internal
            view
            returns (bool)
        {
            if (
                userList[pubkey1].friendList.length >
                userList[pubkey2].friendList.length
            ) {
                address tmp = pubkey1;
                pubkey1 = pubkey2;
                pubkey2 = tmp;
            }
    
            for (uint256 i = 0; i < userList[pubkey1].friendList.length; i++) {
                if (userList[pubkey1].friendList[i].pubkey == pubkey2) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    
        function _addFriend(
            address me,
            address friend_key,
            string memory name
        ) internal {
            Friend memory newFriend = Friend(friend_key, name);
            userList[me].friendList.push(newFriend);
        }
    
        //GET MY FRIEND
        function getMyFriendList() external view returns (Friend[] memory) {
            return userList[msg.sender].friendList;
        }
    
        //get chat code
        function _getChatCode(address pubkey1, address pubkey2)
            internal
            pure
            returns (bytes32)
        {
            if (pubkey1 < pubkey2) {
                return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(pubkey1, pubkey2));
            } else return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(pubkey2, pubkey1));
        }
    
        //SEND MESSAGE
        function sendMessage(address friend_key, string memory _msg) external {
            require(checkUserExists(msg.sender), "Create an account first");
            require(checkUserExists(friend_key), "User is not registered");
            require(
                checkAlreadyFriend(msg.sender, friend_key),
                "You are not friend with the given user"
            );
            bytes32 chatCode = _getChatCode(msg.sender, friend_key);
            Message memory newMsg = Message(msg.sender, block.timestamp, _msg);
            allMessages[chatCode].push(newMsg);
        }
    
        //READ MESSAGE
        function readMessage(address friend_key)
            external
            view
            returns (Message[] memory)
        {
            bytes32 chatCode = _getChatCode(msg.sender, friend_key);
            return allMessages[chatCode];
        }
    
        function getAllUsers() public view returns (AllUserStruct[] memory) {
            return getAllUsers();
        }
    }
```